# Affix is not a function

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to create a sticky sidebar for a while on my Wordpress site with Bootstrap 4 Alpha. I've found other issues similar to this one online and most suggest putting the code inside of

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
});
```

I've tried this but was not successful. I've also tried rearranging the order of how my scripts are being called and that hasn't worked either.

Here is the basic Bootstrap sidebar code that I currently have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#sidebar').affix({
      offset: {
        top: 245
      }
});

var $body   = $(document.body);
var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10;

$body.scrollspy({
    target: '#leftCol',
    offset: navHeight
});
});
```

And here is the error message

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).affix is not a function

Would anyone happen to know why this issue is occurring?

Thanks

Comment: check, you are referencing jquery correctly ? or data-spy with html element

Comment: Good Bye Affix, try with another library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Affix is removed from bootstrap version 4.
[Bootstrap 4 documentation says](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components)--

> Dropped the Affix jQuery plugin. We recommend using a position: sticky polyfill instead. See the HTML5 Please entry for details and specific polyfill recommendations.
>
> If you were using Affix to apply additional, non-position styles, the
>   polyfills might not support your use case. One option for such uses is
>   the third-party ScrollPos-Styler library.

Now comes the remedy for it---

[Take a look at it it should help you to achieve what you want](http://www.codeply.com/go/LDHQhWUG0x)

Comment: Thanks for helping me figure this out! I should do a better job reading the documentation next time.

Answer (score 1):

[Affix was dropped from bootstrap v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components), and they recommend using `position: sticky;` polyfill instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use sticky position with css.

Good example may seen here: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem,
This is way I solve it

use bootstrap.js version 3.0 and it working

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

if it not work? try this: update jquery and bootstrap

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, especially when the question is Bootstrap 4 specific.